# How to get multiple table data in one query in posgresql JSONB data type

Tags: postgresql

How can I Fetch table data in one query? I have below tables:

Tabel Name: calorieTracker

```
  Creat Table calorieTracker(c_id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, caloriesConsumption jsonb);
INSERT INTO public."calorieTracker" ("caloriesConsumption")
VALUES ('[{"C_id":"1",,"calorie":88,"date":"19/08/2020"},{"C_id":2,"date":"19/08/2020","calorie":87}]');
```

Table Name: watertracker

```
create table watertracker(wt_id serial not null primary key, wt_date varchar, wt_goal float,wt_cid int);
INSERT INTO public.watertracker (wt_id,wt_date,wt_goal,wt_cid)
VALUES (2,'2020-08-19',5.5,2);
```

What I am looking here I want to write query where date is 19/08/2020(in calorieTracker table and water tracker table) and wt_cid is 2(water tracker table) and c_id is 2(calorieTracker table) then return data.

Comment: What have you tried? Which part of this are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mentioned what output you want, so i am assuming you want `JSON` object from `caloriesConsumption` which matches the condition mentioned in the question:

based on above assumption try this query:

```
with cte as (
select 
c_id, 
jsonb_array_elements("caloriesConsumption") "data" 
from "calorieTracker"
) 
 select 
 t1.* 
 from cte t1 inner join watertracker t2 
 on t2.wt_cid=cast(t1.data->>'c_id' as int) 
 and t2.wt_date=t1.data->>'date'
```

if you want the result from `watertracker` then just replace `t1.*` with `t2.*`.